# How to remove more than one spaces in between words and sentences of contents source code?

Tags: html, regex, xhtml, dreamweaver

How to remove More Than One Spaces In Between Words of contents in dreamweaver source view. when i copy any data from MS word and paste in Dreaweaver. dreamweaver shows many unneeded spaces in source code. which is showing also in html output like extra space betwwen word and extra space after "." fullstop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning regex tag you should be able replace " +" with " " (Both without quotes). That will destroy all subsequent spaces after first one.

Also you can search for "[ \t]+" instead of " +" in order to "eat" tab characters too.

Comment: I never used dreamweaver, but in case you can use regexes for search and replace, the pattern I provided should do the trick. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_03.html - describes how to do regex-enabled search and replace as well as regex basics.

Comment: @nord- it's not working is space is after fullstop "." in source content